# Error en Método rails (aws-sdk)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Mi error aparece cuando intento subir un archivo a mi s3:

Este es el error:

```
NoMethodError in UploadsController#create
undefined method `write' for #<Aws::S3::Object:0x007ff0981bb850>
```

Esta es la descripción del error:

```
# Upload the file
    obj.write(
      file: params[:file],
      acl: :public_read
    )
```

Y este es mi código (Mi Controlador)

```
class UploadsController < ApplicationController

  def new

  end

  def create

    # Make an object in your bucket for your upload
    obj = S3_BUCKET.object(params[:file].original_filename)

    # Upload the file
    obj.write(
      file: params[:file],
      acl: :public_read
    )

    # Create an object for the upload
    @upload = Upload.new(
            url: obj.public_url,
            name: obj.key
        )

    # Save the upload
    if @upload.save
      redirect_to uploads_path, success: 'File successfully uploaded'
    else
      flash.now[:notice] = 'There was an error'
      render :new
    end
  end

  def index
    @uploads = Upload.all
  end
end
```

Estoy usando la versión 2 de aws-sdk, pero al parecer si está bien:

Porque esto es lo que me trae:

Parameters:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"KNpjxo3vZBXKpno9JVGJXu69fxBpwjNdfY8p1f9fleaaecfk3I7avRk42v5FqKwIqMS6puX2Qm9GJhrn5rCB+w==",
 "file"=>
  #<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007ff0a8030890
   @content_type="image/jpeg",
   @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"lake-louise-alberta.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n",
   @original_filename="lake-louise-alberta.jpg",
   @tempfile=#<File:/tmp/RackMultipart20170815-9057-16b57sd.jpg>>,
 "commit"=>"Upload file"}
```

Saludos!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El método `write` funciona únicamente en la **versión 1 de *aws-sdk***, en la versión 2 este método **no existe**<sup>1</sup>, por lo tanto te arroja el error:

> ```
> NoMethodError in UploadsController#create undefined method `write' for
> #<Aws::S3::Object:0x007ff0981bb850>
> ```

En la versión 2 se recomienda utilizar el método `upload_file` o, para archivos que no están en tu almacenamiento local (como en tu caso), utilizar [`put`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/Aws/S3/Object.html#put-instance_method)<sup>2</sup>; por ejemplo:

```
obj.put(body: params[:file], acl: "public_read")
```

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> *Puedes consultar los métodos disponibles para la clase `Aws::S3::Object` en la [documentación de AWS](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/Aws/S3/Object.html).*</sup>

<sup><sup>2</sup> *[Guía de AWS](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/es_es/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UploadObjSingleOpRuby.html) para subir un archivo utilizando la versión 2.*</sup>

Comment: Gracias, pude solucionar mi problema.